# Annotations in markdown

Tags: markdown

I have searched Google and SO, and don't know if SO is the place to ask this, but I was wondering if there is markup for doing annotations of some type for markdown? We do docs in markdown for our project and would like to do annotations between team members without changing the contents. Maybe I am asking this wrong, but I hope this makes sense. As of now, I am guessing there is not as I have not found an answer, and hoping someone else has found a way to do such a thing.

Thank you for any help that can be offered.

Comment: What do you mean by annotations? Html formatted comments `<!-- this is a comment -->` should work.

Comment: So those work in markdown?

Comment: there are lots of markdown flavours. If you use `pandoc` to convert markdown documents to html or pdf or whatever, yes, they work (ie. they appear in the markdown source, but are not visible in the final document)

Answer (score 13):

#### For comments:

Use HTML formatted comments (as scoa noted):

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

[HTML is a part of the markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the
>   tags.

#### For footnotes:

Footnotes are not part of the [offical/original markdown specification](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

But some markdown flavours support `[^1] / [^1]:` syntax, for example:

```
Some Text. [^footnote]

[^footnote]: This is a footnote.
```

Answer (score 5):

I think

http://criticmarkup.com/

might be a solution. It offeres a special syntax for additions, deletions, changes and comments, as well as a machinery to highlight these changes.

Comment: it seems they're mostly about edit tracking, but it seems really nice extension that one can abuse into annotations and get the other functionality in passing